# Is there a way of getting outerHTML of outerHTML of a web element using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I am using this for get a row in a table:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Sample Text')]")
html_text = element.get_attribute('outerHTML')
```

this gives me `<td>...</td>` but I want `<tr><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>`

How do I do this?

Comment: Can you share HTML for the same?

Comment: Try `//tr[contains(.,'Sample Text')]` or `//tr[td[contains(text(),'Sample Text')]]`

Comment: You need to share the relevant `HTML` along with the `outerHTML` which you are trying to retrieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get outerHTML of parent element, you can use below

```
html_text = element.find_element_by_xpath('..').get_attribute('outerHTML')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String `val=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='fileToUpload']")).getAttribute("outerHTML");`
```

**For Java**,Tested in 2020 with chrome 83 which gives 
Outter html value is